# What virtual machine can I use to virtualize Mac OS in Windows?

Tags: macos, virtualization, osx-leopard

I want to run Mac OS in my Windows operative system, is there any virtual machine that does that? Tnks.

Comment: Superuser is better for this type of question

Comment: Which is currently in closed beta?

Comment: just need the codeword: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is against the Mac OS X End User License Agreement to run the OS on hardware other than that provided by Apple.

...In other news, VMWare is a good virtualization product, *cough*.

Comment: You might want to talk to a lawyer though, as some statements in EULAs can be conflicting with the law.

Comment: Maybe if you install windows on a mac and then run osx in a virtual machine it's allowed?

Comment: I believe that the only version of Mac OS X that is "allowed" to run in a VM is Mac OS X Server.  So I suppose that if you were to buy a Mac that included OS X Server or buy any Mac that could run OS X Server and OS X Server seperately, then you could potentially do Andrej' suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OS X Server is the only one that VM like VMWare and Parallels support with out "tweaking". There are several articles out there on how to get OS X client to run.

If you have a machine to dedicate, you could always set up a XEN Server. That is what I do for my VM needs. They can be running and I just remote into them as needed.